# preg_replace not removing unwanted period

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm needing to search an entire HTML document for lines such as:

```
<img alt="Suppliers" class="showme 2-4supp" src="./images/2-4supp.jpg" />
```

and replace the `./` with the variable stored in `$prepend`.

This is the code I can almost get to work:

```
$mypage = preg_replace('/src=\"([.])*?/', "src=\"$prepend_href$1", $mypage);
```

However, the results that I get are:

```
<img alt="Suppliers" class="showme 2-4supp" src="02_topic/./images/2-4supp.jpg" />
```

It will not remove the `.` from the string.  I've tried different methods, and I can get it to add the variable but I can't get it to remove the . from the string.

Comment: `02_topic/./images/2-4supp.jpg` and `02_topic/images/2-4supp.jpg` point to the same file

Answer (score 0):

Why `*?` in front of period, it should be replaced with:

```
$mypage = preg_replace('#src="\.(?=/)#', "src=\"$prepend_href", $mypage);
```

Comment: Or use: `$mypage = preg_replace('#src="\.(?=/)#i', "src=\"$prepend_href", $mypage);` is your HTML can have mixed case `SRC` image attribute.

Comment: I'm getting the result of  <img alt="Suppliers" class="showme 2-4supp" src="02_topic//images/2-4supp.jpg" />  Notice the extra /.

Comment: @LisaKomidar: That means your `$prepend_href` has a trailing `/`. In that case use: `$mypage = preg_replace('#src="\./#i', "src=\"$prepend_href", $mypage);`